# Wireless protocol for accelerometer data

Tags: bluetooth, wireless, accelerometer

I'm building an application where a mobile phone with an accelerometer is used to control an app on a computer in a similar way you would use a mouse. So I need to send the movement from the phone to the computer over some wireless protocol. I am thinking about using Bluetooth but I am not sure what transfer delay to expect. Another possibility is using 802.11g. What do you think? What delay could I expect given that I don’t hit the bandwidth limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked with a group at Motorola who linked up an external accelerometer pack to a mobile phone using Bluetooth.  This work supported a mobile games development class at USC's GamePipe Laboratory, and the speed was sufficient to control the mobile games developed by the students.  You'll need to make sure your handset's Bluetooth stack has the correct profile enabled to allow data communication.

Answer (score 0):

Another advantage of Bluetooth over 802.11g is that the frequency hopping Bluetooth uses will make it less vulnerable to interference by all the other 802.11 devices in the vicinity, which sit on one frequency.

I wouldn't expect the amount of data sent by an accelerometer would give Bluetooth any problems.